# Showing Cypriot names for Cyprus on OpenStreetMap

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, cyprus

How can I show only cypriot names (instead of Turkish) in OpenLayers map for the northern Cyprus side?

By default OpenStreetMap shows both Turkish and Cypriot.

https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/35.1278/33.6362&layers=C

[image]

In OpenLayers it only shows Turkish names.

[image]

Comment: you are going to need another osm source that agrees with your point of view

Comment: If you use a source such as MapTiler you can customise the standard style, save it then follow the instructions on how to use raster tiles it generates in OpenLayers.https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JM0f.png

Comment: I use `var roadLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})` How can i customize it?

Comment: You would need to use new ol.source.XYZ() with a url from MapTiler

Comment: Customising OSM is the way to go although it might take some time to achieve what you want. In the mean time, you could try other providers e.g. ESRI offers a few basemaps with localised place names see https://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=702026e41f6641fb85da88efe79dc166&view=list&start=1&num=20#content

Comment: @TheVRChris Is thisone free to use for production?  https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=67372ff42cd145319639a99152b15bc3

Comment: @Andd It seems ESRI requires that you must have some ESRI software or an ArcGIS Online subscription to use those basemaps, take a look at their summarized terms of use: http://downloads2.esri.com/ArcGISOnline/docs/tou_summary.pdf and the various details can be found here: https://www.esri.com/en-us/legal/terms/full-master-agreement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternative tile source like Thunderforest which is used by OpenSteetMap

`https://tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png`

or even:

`https://tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/${z}/${x}/${y}.png`

For more alternative tile sources see: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers

Comment: This does not require a registration to get an API key?

Comment: Yes, it's free for up to 150,000 tile requests per month: https://www.thunderforest.com/pricing/ . For the Landscape baseman, details on how to use the tile URL can be found here: https://www.thunderforest.com/maps/landscape/